# Full path of running processes in Android?

Tags: command-line, android

I have a rooted install of Android on my phone and a terminal emulator.  I can run `su` and then commands like `ps` and `top`, however they only show me things like `com.android.deskclock` for running apps, rather than a full path to an executable.  Is there a way for me to get the full path for these running apps?

Comment: Apps on Android doesn't have a Native-Program-ish full path, an installed app is roughly a directory containing its Java classes (possibly with some AOT compiled code)

Comment: It might be better if you show your results of `ps` or `top` in the question

Answer (score 4):

You can get the full path of the executable just like on any Linux system with:

```
readlink /proc/PID/exe
```

However, for *all* the android *apps*, that's just `/system/bin/app_process32` or `/system/bin/app_process64` ie the same executable as the `main`/`zygote` process (itself started by `init`).

That process will just fork children process which will then load the java classes making up an Android app, without `exec()`ing any extra binary.

The command lines you see in the output of `ps` (`/proc/PID/cmdline`) are just "faked" as usual by overwriting the `argv` block -- see [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/e6024b34edaa57817149b94da563dddd5ee30764/core/jni/AndroidRuntime.cpp#323).

Comment: OK, so is there a way I can find out which actual Java files Android is using for a particular app's process?

Comment: Use `pm list packages -f` to list both names and files of each app, IIRC. I'm not able to check just now.

Comment: That seems to work.  Thanks.